# Nagios plugin to monitor FreeSWITCH

Tags: monitoring, nagios, nrpe, freeswitch

I am trying to configure Nagios to monitor FreeSWITCH as mentioned at https://github.com/kjhosein/nagios-freeswitch-plugin .

I have downloaded the script from git and followed listed steps.

On remote (NRPE) server I have added below line in nrpe.cfg file

```
command[check_freeswitch_health]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_freeswitch_health.pl $ARG1$
```

On Nagios server,added in commands.cfg file

```
define command {
    command_name    check_freeswitch_health
    command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c check_freeswitch_health $ARG1$
  }
```

and in services.cfg file

```
define service {
    host_name       freeswitch01
    service_description     FreeSWITCH - Calls Count
    check_command   check_freeswitch_health!-a '-q show-calls-count'!!!!!!!
  }
```

But on Nagios web interface I am getting

```
CHECK_NRPE: Received 0 bytes from daemon. Check the remote server logs for error messages.
```

On remote server, logs(/var/log/syslog) showing below error

```
Request contained command arguments!
Client request was invalid, bailing out...
```

What I am missing here ? Can anyone please assist me with correct configurations ?

Thanks,

Rutu

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you can run that perl script locally, as the nagios/nrpe user.
2. Make sure that perl script doesn't depend on ENV (e.g., $PATH). Verify by running through `env -i /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_freeswitch_health.pl ...`
3. Use your generic `check_nrpe` command definition, instead of writing a check_{whatever} for every different NRPE command you want to run.
4. To pass args with -a, you must enable command arguments in nrpe.cfg by setting `dont_blame_nrpe=1`

For example, if your `check_nrpe` command looks like this:

```
define command {
    command_name    check_nrpe
    command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ -a $ARG2$
}
```

Then your service definition would be:

```
define service {
    host_name       freeswitch01
    service_description     FreeSWITCH - Calls Count
    check_command   check_nrpe!check_freeswitch_health!-q show-calls-count
}
```

(Why do you have !!!!!!! at the end of your command?)

Or, if the only option you ever pass to that perl script is `-q`, you can put it in the command definition in the NRPE config:

```
command[check_freeswitch_health]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_freeswitch_health.pl -q $ARG1$
```

Then your `check_command` would be just `check_nrpe!check_freeswitch_health!show-calls-count`

Comment: Hi Keith,
Thank you for detailed explanation to my query.

1.Make sure you can run that perl script locally, as the nagios/nrpe user.
>>How can I check that perl script is run as nagios/nrpe user?

2.Make sure that perl script doesn't depend on ENV (e.g., $PATH).
>>When I run env -i /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_freeswitch_health.pl -q show-calls-count on nrpe server,it gives:
REESWITCH_HEALTH OK - Result of check is: 0 total.  | show-calls-count=0;;

Comment: 3.Use your generic check_nrpe command definition, instead of writing a check_{whatever} for every different NRPE command you want to run.
>> I have tried as you have suggested but still getting same issue.

I have script check_freeswitch_health.pl at /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/
Is there any specific steps to install nagios-freeswitch-plugin ?

Comment: Added a step 4 for you ;-) Not sure how I missed this the first time, sorry.